# Is there a setting or way to have pandas warn or alert when doing operations with dataframes that are not the same size?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following snippet is an example of an operation I would like an alert or warning for. Not sure if there is some methodology or setting in pandas to avoid situations like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,-6,-8,-9],columns=['nums'])
np.sign(df) * df[df['nums'] > 0]

   nums
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   3.0
3   4.0
4   5.0
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   NaN
```

`np.sign(df)` will be longer than `df[df['nums'] > 0]` resulting in `NaN`s appended and a mismatched multiplication

Answer (score 0):

I think I misunderstood how pandas handles situations like this. `np.sign(df)` has the full index `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=8, step=1)`, but `df[df['nums'] > 0]` has a smaller index `Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')`. The indices are used to decide what to multiple what to what, so this issue isn't as bad as I originally thought. I guess a `isna()` check afterwards would suffice.